# count occurrences of values in an associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me on how to count the occurrences of value in this associative array.

```
<?php
$employees = array(
   1 => array(
       'name' => 'Jason Alipala',
       'employee_id' => 'G1001-05',
       'position' => 1             
   ),
   2 => array(
       'name' => 'Bryann Revina',
       'employee_id' => 'G1009-03',
       'position' => 2           
   ),
   3 => array(
       'name' => 'Jeniel Mangahis',
       'employee_id' => 'G1009-04',
       'position' => 2
   ),
   4 => array(
       'name' => 'Arjay Bussala',
       'employee_id' => 'G1009-05',
       'position' => 3        
   ),
   5 => array(
       'name' => 'Ronnel Ines',
       'employee_id' => 'G1002-06',
       'position' => 3           
   )
   );

?>
```

This is my code from fake_db.php which I *include_once* in the index.php. I want to count the occurrences of the same value of 'position'.. e.g. 1 = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 2

in addition, there is another array named $positions...

```
$positions = array(
    1 => 'TL',
    2 => 'Programmer',
    3 => 'Converter');
```

this array is where i compare the 'position' from the $employees array.

any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What you have tried so far post your attempts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Combination of `array_count_values` & `array_column` *(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)* should work -

```
$counts = array_count_values(
    array_column($employees, 'position')
);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(2)
}
```

**Update**

```
$final = array_filter($counts, function($a) {
   return $a >= 2;
});
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(2)
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/487350)

Comment: Bose specify the versions too. as `array_column` might be used within **5.5**

Comment: i got your codes but what I want to display is not array. just a variable.. for example i only want to display how many of them has the value of '2' on the 'position' category. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

array_column — Return the values from a single column of array. array_count_values — Counts all the values of an array.

```
$positions = array_column($employees, 'position');
print_r(array_count_values($positions));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop will do the job. Take an array, keep the key as the actual value and the value in the key as COUNTER of that key.
if the key exists in array that means it has the value just increment else assign 1 to initialize the key with value 1.

e.g.   1=>counter of 1 (occurrences)

```
 $arrayCounter=0;

 foreach($employees as $value){
     foreach($value as $data){
          $position = $data['position'];
        if(array_key_exists($position,$arrayCounter)){
             $arrayCounter[$position] = arrayCounter[$position]++;
        }
       else{ 
           $arrayCounter[$position] = 1;  
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. The array `$employees` is the array you have supplied. You can use this code:

```
$data = array();

foreach($employees as $employee) {
    if(isset($data[$employee['position']])) {
        $data[$employee['position']]++;
    } else {
        $data[$employee['position']] = 1;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

This gives the output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_count_value() pre-define php function to get your aim.
you can see result [here](https://eval.in/487354)

Answer (score 0):

```
        $total = 0;
        foreach($employees as $eNum => $value){
            if($aEmployees[$eNum]['position'] == $key){
                $total++;
            }
        }
        echo $total;
```

These codes are inside a function that is called on every iteration of a foreach loop(another array named '$positions')..
$key is a variable that contains value from that foreach loop (the '$positions' array).. this is what I've done, and it works for me. But i don't know if this is the proper way?